# entered form data is not saving in mysql db?

Tags: php, mysql

**Here is my code which is not working properly**

```
 <?php
 include('admin/class.php');
```

**Here is my db connection:**

```
 $hostname="localhost";
 $username="root";
 $password="";
 $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
 or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
 echo "Connected to MySQL<br>"; 
 $se = mysql_select_db("timesheet1234",$dbhandle)
   or die("Could not select timesheet1234");
 echo "connected to db";
```

**Here am doing  the functionality after clicking the button:**

```
 if(isset($_POST['save']))
 {  
 $sel=@$_POST['selpro'];
 $mon=@$_POST['mon'];
 $tue=@$_POST['tue'];
 $wed=@$_POST['wed'];
 $thu=@$_POST['thu'];
 $fri=@$_POST['fri'];
 $sat=@$_POST['sat'];
 $sun=@$_POST['sun'];
```

**Here am writing the query functionality**

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
 {
 echo "session user";
 $sql="UPDATE empdaytimesheet SET 
`project code`='$sel',`mon`='$mon',`tue`='$tue',`wed`='$wed',`thu`='$thu',`
 fri`='$fri',`sat`='$sat',`sun`='$sun' where `username`='".$_SESSION['user']."'";

 $res=mysql_query($sql,$dbhandle);
```

**Here is the problem where it is not working:**

```
    if($res){
         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
         echo "alert('TimeSheet Saved..!')";
         echo "</script>";
         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
         echo "window.location='my_timesheet.php'";
         echo "</script>";
      }
      else
      {
         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
         echo "alert('Some Error Occured ! Retry..!')";
         echo "</script>";
         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
         echo "window.location='my_timesheet.php'";
         echo "</script>";
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: It's OK for testing, but don't use mysql_* functions on a live site, as they are deprecated and not very secure. Also, supressing the error when an index is undefined in $_POST is not the way to do it, the error still occurs, you just don't see it.

Comment: Do you get any output?

Comment: yes am getting the successful alert that is timesheet saved

Comment: using `@` (error suppression) is very heavy on processing and also wont show you any errors. instead use `Try Catch` block for handling any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the '@' before $_POST and you should be fine.

However, your current script looks like it's vulnerable to SQLi.

And you are also using a deprecated extension. You should consider using MySQLi or PDO instead.

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?#tab-top) on more information on how to make your code more secure.

Comment: Then you are probably doing it wrong. Post the code you use for MySQLi and I'll help you the best I can.

Comment: <?php
      include('admin/class.php');
      $hostname="localhost"; 
      $username="root";
      $password="";
      $dbhandle = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
      or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
      echo "Connected to MySQL<br>"; 
      
       if(isset($_POST['save']))
         {  
        $sel=@$_POST['selpro'];
        $mon=@$_POST['mon'];
         $tue=@$_POST['tue'];
        $wed=@$_POST['wed'];    
        $thu=@$_POST['thu'];
        $fri=@$_POST['fri'];
        $sat=@$_POST['sat'];
        $sun=@$_POST['sun'];

Comment: $se = mysqli_select_db("timesheet1234",$dbhandle)
      or die("Could not select timesheet1234");
      echo "connected to db";
       if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
           {
    echo "session user";
    $sql="UPDATE empdaytimesheet SET `project ode`='$sel',`mon`='$mon',`tue`='$tue',`wed`='$wed',`thu`='$thu',`fri`='$fri',`sat`='$sat',`sun`='$sun' where `username`='".$_SESSION['user']."'";
$res=mysqli_query($sql,$dbhandle)or  die("Could not run the query properly");

Comment: if($res){
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo "alert('TimeSheet Saved..!')";
echo "</script>";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo "window.location='my_timesheet.php'";
echo "</script>";
       }

Comment: else
{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo "alert('Some Error Occured ! Retry..!')";
echo "</script>";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo "window.location='my_timesheet.php'";
echo "</script>";
}
}
}
?>